# rstrip not removing newline char what am I doing wrong?

Tags: python, newline

Pulling my hair out here... have been playing around with this for the last hour but I cannot get it to do what I want, ie. remove the newline sequence.

```
def add_quotes( fpath ):

        ifile = open( fpath, 'r' )
        ofile = open( 'ofile.txt', 'w' )

        for line in ifile:
            if line == '\n': 
                ofile.write( "\n\n" )
            elif len( line ) > 1:
                line.rstrip('\n')
                convertedline = "\"" + line + "\", "
                ofile.write( convertedline )

        ifile.close()
        ofile.close()
```

Answer (score 36, accepted):

The clue is in the signature of `rstrip`.

It returns a copy of the string, but with the desired characters stripped, thus you'll need to assign `line` the new value:

```
line = line.rstrip('\n')
```

This allows for the sometimes very handy chaining of operations:

```
"a string".strip().upper()
```

As [Max. S](https://stackoverflow.com/users/181765/max-s) says in the comments, Python strings are immutable which means that any "mutating" operation will yield a mutated copy.

This is how it works in many frameworks and languages. If you really need to have a mutable string type (usually for performance reasons) there are string buffer classes.

Comment: More generally, strings in Python are immutable. Once created, they can't be changed. Any function that does something to a string returns a copy.

Comment: Indeed. Maybe I should put that in the answer.

Comment: Thanks, I new it had to be something simple, ...my own fault for only skimming through python doc.

Comment: @max thanks for mentioning that.

Answer (score 3):

you can do it like this

```
def add_quotes( fpath ):
        ifile = open( fpath, 'r' )
        ofile = open( 'ofile.txt', 'w' )
        for line in ifile:
            line=line.rstrip()
            convertedline = '"' + line + '", '
            ofile.write( convertedline + "\n" )
        ifile.close()
        ofile.close()
```

Answer (score 3):

As alluded to in Skurmedel's answer and the comments, you need to do something like:

```
stripped_line = line.rstrip()
```

and then write out stripped_line.